# Rails 6 webpack not loading stylesheets + bootstrap?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, webpack

I have started a project in Rails 6 and I have followed the guidelines, I have taken a Bootstrap template with HTML and CSS, but when loading the view it does not show me bootstrap or custom scss.

Bootstrap installed with yarn, and I have the css in javascripts / stylesheets / _home.scss, if I put the style in plain view if it detects it, but having it in the pack is not loading it for me, someone knows why it could be ?

javascript/packs/application.js

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

import 'bootstrap'
import '../stylesheets/application'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all'
```

javascript/stylesheets/application.scss

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
@import "home";
@import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free";
```

webpack/environment.js

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker');

const webpack = require('webpack');

environment.plugins.append("Provide", new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
}));

environment.config.set('resolve.alias', {jquery: 'jquery/src/jquery'});

module.exports = environment;
```

webpacker.yml

```
# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  check_yarn_integrity: false
  webpack_compile_output: true

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: false

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Verifies that correct packages and versions are installed by inspecting package.json, yarn.lock, and node_modules
  check_yarn_integrity: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    pretty: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "callcenter",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.1",
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "4.2.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for help ^^

Comment: As far as I know `stylesheets/application.scss` should be inside `app/assets` directory because your `application.html.erb` might be using `stylesheet_link_tag`.

Comment: i had stylesheet_pack_tag in application.html.erb, i solved it adding `import 'core-js/stable'
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'` in the top of application.js

Comment: Nice to hear that you are able to solve the problem.